# Repair set up option in setup installation?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I made a setup file for c#.net application and installed it now when I restart the setup it is showing me the following error:

> Another version of this product is already being installed. Installation of this version can not  continue.

I want to create a setup with repair a option and somewhere I read that this repair option is provided by default then why I am not able to get that?

Need help, thanks.

Comment: What have you researched? Ofcourse you will get that error when you restart the set up. If your making a repair, you need to make a decision 1. Load the uninstaller first, the re-install the program. 2. Find the broken parts of the program by checking the existing program with the actual program ( going to be harder ofcourse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of setup project have you used?

If you want your installer/setup to overwrite existing installation then you must increase the version number, every time you build installer project.

Version number consists of 4 parts 0.0.0.0 (Major Version, Minor Version, Build Number, Revision Number) but windows installer consider only first 3 parts so, make sure to increase the build number, every time you build a new installer.

If you run the same installer after installation was already completed successfully then it will ask you to remove the installation but if the installer is new but with same version number (you rebuild the installer project but did not change the version number) then you will get the in question message.

Select setup project in Visual studio > F4 > change the Version number (increase the build number by 1)

Comment: can you tell me one more thing, after installation when i run the program it shows the error about image in resource folder actually it is unable to find the resource folder, can you tell me how should i include the resources folder in my setup process ?

Comment: assuming you are using Visual studio installer project: follow the steps: Right click on setup project -> View -> File System. Create a new folder in Application folder. add all your resources to the newly created folder. Whatever (files and folders) you put in Application Data Folder it will be copied over to your installation target directory

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [ARPNOMODIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367590%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [ARPNOREPAIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367592%28VS.85%29.aspx) properties